# Right margin numeration / referencing LATEX

Tags: numbering, margins, footnotes

I need to make same format article in latex as in attached img, but I don't have any previous knowledge. I sorted out most of stuff. But cannot understand what are the right margin numbers and footnotes.Any help would be appreciated

Here is test text with achievements done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}
\date{April 2015}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\linenumbers
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\section{Introduction}
The Verge ist ein amerikanisches Technikportal und Mediennetzwerk. Das Unternehmen ist ein Tochterunternehmen von Vox Media mit Sitz in Manhattan, New York. Veröffentlicht werden Nachrichtenmeldungen, Leitartikel, Produktrezensionen, Podcasts und eine eigene Unterhaltungssendung \footnote{This is a footnote}.
Die Seite wird mit Vox Medias proprietärer Publishing-Plattform Chorus betrieben. Finanziert wird The Verge durch Werbeeinnahmen und Sponsoren. An der Spitze stehen Chefredakteur Nilay Patel, Redakteur Dieter Bohn und Geschäftsführer von Vox Media Jim Bankoff. Die Seite ist seit dem 1. November 2011 aktiv.

\section{Entstehung}
Im Jahr 2002 begann AOL eine Strategie zum Ausbau von werbefinanzierten Inhalten zu verfolgen, welche den Kauf von bereits etablierten Webseiten beinhaltete.[5] Eine der ersten Zukäufe war Weblogs, Inc. im Jahr 2005, ein Unternehmen, welches mehrere Webseiten, darunter das Technikportal Engadget, betrieb.[5] Laut Business Insider wurde Engadget zur "führenden Gadget-Webseite der Branche" („industry leading gadget site“) und dadurch zu AOL’s "populärsten und wichtigsten\footnote{2nd footnote} Besitz im Medienbereich" („most popular and important media property“).

Im Jahr 2007 wurde Joshua Topolsky zum Chefredakteur von Engadget und war zuständig für „The Engadget Show“ und deren mobile Applikation sowie das kontinuierliche Wachstum der Seite.[5] Nach der Übernahme von TechCrunch im Jahr 2011 kam es zu ersten Feindseligkeiten zwischen Topolsky und AOL. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` should be added ;-)

Comment: Can you show us more of the image. I think, the right margin numbers refer to other lines on the same page and are 'comments'

Answer (score 2):

Some workaround as a combination of `\marginote` and `\footnote`:

`\footmarginnote[optional number]{some text}[optional margin text]` will print the footnote number in the right margin and the corresponding 'footnote' without marker as a real footnote.

If the optional argument is given, that number (no check so far!) is used instead of the current footnote number!

There is no connection to other line numbers. This can be achieved using a `\linelabel` and an explicit `\ref{somelabel}` statement as 3rd. optional argument of `\footmarginnote` (see the example with `\linelabel{Nachrichtenmeldungen}`, please)

Please use `\footmarginnote` without white space in front of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\title{test}
\date{April 2015}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\footmarginnote}{o+mo}{%
  \stepcounter{footnote}%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \footnotetext[#1]{#2}%
    \marginnote{\footnotesize#1}
  }{%
    \footnotetext{#2}%
    \IfValueTF{#3}{%
      \marginnote{\footnotesize#3}%
    }{%
      \marginnote{\footnotesize\arabic{footnote}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\linenumbers
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\section{Introduction}
The Verge ist ein amerikanisches Technikportal und Mediennetzwerk. Das Unternehmen ist ein Tochterunternehmen von Vox Media mit Sitz in Manhattan, New York. Veröffentlicht werden Nachrichtenmeldungen\linelabel{Nachrichtenmeldungen}, Leitartikel, Produktrezensionen, Podcasts und eine eigene Unterhaltungssendung\footmarginnote{This is a footnote}.
Die Seite wird mit Vox Medias proprietärer Publishing-Plattform Chorus betrieben. Finanziert wird The Verge durch Werbeeinnahmen und Sponsoren. An der Spitze stehen Chefredakteur Nilay Patel, Redakteur Dieter Bohn und Geschäftsführer von Vox Media Jim Bankoff.\footmarginnote{Blabla}[Refering to \ref{Nachrichtenmeldungen}] Die Seite ist seit dem 1. November 2011 aktiv.

\section{Entstehung}
Im Jahr 2002 begann AOL eine Strategie zum Ausbau von werbefinanzierten Inhalten zu verfolgen, welche den Kauf von bereits etablierten Webseiten beinhaltete.[5] Eine der ersten Zukäufe war Weblogs, Inc. im Jahr 2005, ein Unternehmen, welches mehrere Webseiten, darunter das Technikportal Engadget, betrieb.[5] Laut Business Insider wurde Engadget zur "führenden Gadget-Webseite der Branche" („industry leading gadget site“) und dadurch zu AOL’s "populärsten und wichtigsten\footmarginnote[13]{2nd footnote} Besitz im Medienbereich" („most popular and important media property“).

Im Jahr 2007 wurde Joshua Topolsky zum Chefredakteur von Engadget und war zuständig für „The Engadget Show“ und deren mobile Applikation sowie das kontinuierliche Wachstum der Seite.[5] Nach der Übernahme von TechCrunch im Jahr 2011 kam es zu ersten Feindseligkeiten zwischen Topolsky und AOL. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remark: Toggling the position of the line numbers should lead to a toggle of the position of the margin note

Comment: Christian Hupfer, thanks for your prompt reply. I wanted to make some more remarks, that I got today from my prof. The numbers on the right side represent the page number in original text. The footnotes mean remarks on certain line number, and all of the footnotes should be in one line.