# Notes above bottom margin

Tags: margins, footnotes, footmisc

I am writing a paper in latex and there is one part that I could not find how to resolve, I need to add some notes on the bottom of the page, before the bottom margin.

- They are not footnotes in real, it will be sort of line remark, and gonna be on several lines. They should appear in the bottom of page before margin and look like a plain text, not a list, with a bit smaller font size. In image below, there is an example. The form is like: `[lineno] remark`

Here is the code I ve done till now (text is random)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno, marginnote, amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=2.5cm, marginparsep=0.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\def\linenumberfont{\normalfont\small\sffamily}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\noindent Wikipedia
\newline
Wikipedia (Listeni/ˌwɪkɨˈpiːdiə/ or Listeni/ˌwɪkiˈpiːdiə/ wik-i-pee-dee-ə) is a free-access, free content Internet encyclopedia, supported and hosted by the non-profit Wikimedia Foundation. Those who can access the site and follow its rules can edit most of its articles.[6] Wikipedia is ranked among the ten most popular websites[5] and\underline{ constitutes the} Internet's largest and most popular general reference work.Jimmy Wales and Larry Sanger launched Wikipedia on January 15, 2001. Sanger[10] coined its name,[11] a portmanteau of wiki[notes 2] and encyclopedia. Initially only in English, Wikipedia quickly became multilingual as it developed similar versions in other languages, which differ in content and in editing practices. The English Wikipedia is now one of \underline {more than 200 Wikipedias} and is the largest with over 4.8 million articles. There is a grand total, including all Wikipedias, of nearly 35 million articles in 288 different languages.[13] As of February 2014, it had 18 billion page views and nearly 500 million unique \textbar\space\marginnote{1} visitors each month.[14] Globally, Wikipedia had more than 19 million accounts,[15] out of which there were about 69,000 active editors as of November 2014.
Supporters of Wikipedia cite a \textbar\space\marginnote{6} 2005 survey of Wikipedia published in Nature based on a comparison of 42 science articles with Encyclopædia Britannica, which found that Wikipedia's level of accuracy approached Encyclopdia Britannics.[16] Critics argue Wikipedia exhibits systemic bias. Wikipedia has been criticized for being a mixture of "truths, half truths, and some falsehoods",[17] and subject to manipulation and spin.
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: It sure *looks like* a footnote could be adapted to the task...

Comment: So LaTeX is able to translate on compiling :o)?

Comment: @Bernard, thats just an example image, showing what I want to achieve

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, it might work as well, but I am not that pro in LateX, who is able to adapt predefined functions=)

Comment: Maybe the `bigfoot` package? It offers the possibility of run-in footnotes.

Comment: It's a follow-up question of this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238434/right-margin-numeration-referencing-latex

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes it is!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want "paragraph-style footnotes." You can get these in any document class by loading the `footmisc` package with the `para` option.
You can also use the `memoir` class and issue the command `paragraphfootnotes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

    % OR:
    % \documentclass{memoir}
    % \paragraphfootnotes

\begin{document}
This is an ancient\footnote{Possibly first-century Roman.} palindrome:
Sator\footnote{``The sower''.} Arepo\footnote{Apparently a proper name.} Tenet\footnote{``Holds''.} Opera\footnote{``Works''.} Rotas.\footnote{``Broken''.}
Its meaning is unclear but you can make a magic square with it.
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\Huge

Regular Text

\vfill

Bottom Notes

\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is working actually, but adding everytime newpages might be not that good idea(

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that you wanted the line number preceding each comment.

Comment: The line numbering can be disabled, it is not a big problem, but it will be too time consuming everytime looking whether the text in bottom will fit or not(